# How to apply retention policy to TFS Package Management?

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

Does anyone have any suggestions around package TFS Package Management and how to apply retention of packages?

Without a retention policy, the number of packages and HD space used grows quite quickly particularly for CI Builds.

I would like to use the TFS Package Management, however, I'm leaning towards MyGet simply because it has the ability to apply retention policies.

I would really to hear what other people have done in this regard.

Comment: MyGet is an option as you mentioned it can apply [Package retention](https://docs.myget.org/docs/reference/package-retention) policy, To use it refer to [MyGet with VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/services/myget). Alternately you can also use the [delete API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/packaging/nuget#delete-package), write a delete script, and create a schedule plan to run the script.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to programmaticly delete packages today would be to leverage our [delete APIs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/packaging/nuget#delete-package).

We're aware that this is not a great story and are currently working on implementing retention policies within the product.  You'll be able to enter a setting that says "only retain the latest N versions of my packages" with some tools to provide exceptions.

If you'd like to chat to learn more, feel free to send me a message and we can set up some time!

Comment: Hi @Calvin_Jones_Microsoft that would be great! I know alot of companies that are choosing other solutions like MyGet purely because Package Management doesn't have Retention Policies. Do you know when this will be available to TFS onprem?

Comment: We have it listed in Q4 2017 on our feature timeline (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/), which would translate to TFS 2018 Update 1.  We might slip to Update 2 but will do our best!